# Remove Column based on Column position/index number

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

In PowerBI, M-language I need to remove a specific column number (number 5) for each table column in multiple files. So far I have managed to remove the column by name, but the naming of column 5 varies, I want to remove the column by its columnnumber instead of its columnname.

```
= Table.RemoveColumns(
  Table.PromoteHeaders(Csv.Document([Content], [Delimiter = ";", Columns = 11, Encoding = 1252])), 
  "ColumnName"
)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
= Table.RemoveColumns(x,Table.ColumnNames(x){4})
```

so then probably

```
= Table.RemoveColumns(
  Table.PromoteHeaders(Csv.Document([Content], [Delimiter = ";", Columns = 11, Encoding = 1252]))
, Table.ColumnNames(Table.PromoteHeaders(Csv.Document([Content], [Delimiter = ";", Columns = 11, Encoding = 1252]))){4}
)
```